# Getting Null value in controller while making fetch post request from react

Tags: reactjs, api, asp.net-core

I am trying to make post request from react to .net core controller. While making request I get value of organizationId inside loadUserDetails in react while debugging but in Controller I am getting null value .

```
 // Route to UserDetails
<CDropdownItem to={`/userDetails/${organization.organizationId}`}>
     Users
   </CDropdownItem>


// Calling Api using fetch inside userDetails Component

 const loadUserDetails = () => {
     fetch(Constants.USER_GET_URI, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ organizationId }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setUserDetails(data);
        setLoading(true);
      });
}

//API Controller
 [HttpPost("GetUser")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(int organizationId){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are sending a request body like this:

```json
{
  "organizationId": 123
}
```

The controller should receive it like this:

```cs
public class UserController
{
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser([FromBody] GetUserModel model)
  {
    var organizationId = model.OrganizationId;
    // TODO
  }
}

public class GetUserModel
{
  public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for Reply,It worked. I am new to React and .net core . Can you please explain why cannot I directly use OrganizationId.

Comment: @Nirnayabaral because your API is a post request, and it's expecting to get the JSON you're sending to it from the body.

Comment: When you have "simple" type in the parameters (like int or string), it will try to map it from query parameters or route parameters I think. Complex types are mapped from body by default, so the `[FromBody]` is actually not mandatory here, it's just my preference to use it. You can read more about model binding in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding.